# Не могу обработать кириллицу

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка

Использую `Node.js для` загрузки валют с центробанка.

Гружу `xml` по [ссылке](http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_valFull.asp), в которой есть русскоязычные названия валют. Никак не могу получить эти названия в нормальном виде, как в `Google Chrome`.

В `Fiddler 4` происходит аналогичная ситуация.

```
const request = require('request');
const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const utf8 = require('utf8');

request(URL, (err, result, body) => {
    let a = result.body;// ���������� ���
    let b = body;// ���������� ���
    let c = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(new Buffer(body, 'binary'), 'windows-1251'), 'utf8').toString();// ээээээээээ эээ
    let g = utf8.encode(body);// ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
});
```

Английские символы отображаются корректно, а русские нет.

На месте кракозябр в комментариях должно быть: `Молдавский лей`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант с `let c ..` почти верный. Для работы с бинарными данными вместе с `url`, [надо передать](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) значение `encoding: null`. В итоге примерно так, должно выглядеть:

```
const request = require('request');
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');

let config = {
    url: 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_valFull.asp',
    encoding: null
}

request(config, (err, result, body) => {  
    let c = iconv.encode(iconv.decode(body, 'windows-1251'), 'utf8').toString();
    console.log(c);
})
```